# ArrayList of elements that are of a generic type - can be done?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, collections

I have this interface:

```
public interface Carriable
{
    public abstract String getName();
}
```

And the 2 classes that implement this interface : Passenger and CargoItem

```
public class Passenger implements Carriable 
public class CargoItem implements Carriable
```

I also have a class Compartment that can be either of type Passenger or type CargoItem, not both and has some carriables(passengers/cargoItems)

```
public class Compartment<T extends Carriable>
{
    ...    
    private ArrayList<T> allCarriables;
    ...
}
```

All these are specifies clearly in the problem statemnet.
Now I want to create a Ship class that has "some unique linked compartment". I would want to write

```
public class Ship
{
 private Set<Compartment<T extends Carriable>> allComaprtments;
}
```

in order to be able to add compartments of 2 different types. Why is it not allowed and what would be another approach?

UPDATE :
I want to be able to add compartments of a specific type, for example:

```
Compartment<Passenger> oneComp= new Compartment();  

this.allComaprtments.add(oneComp);
```

Comment: You have already specified in the declaration of Compartment that T extends Carriable. Can you use something like private Set<Compartment<Carriable>> allComaprtments; ?

Comment: The set should be of type Set<Compartment<T>>, and the Ship class should be generic.

Comment: It does not generate an error but I do not know how to add compartments of type passeger or cargo. it does not allow the following : Compartment<Passenger> oneComp= new Compartment();
      this.allComaprtments.add(oneComp);

Comment: You did not declare generic type `T` before so you can't *use* it in your fields description. I am not sure how you want to use this set so maybe you want `Set<Compartment<? extends Carriable>> allComaprtments`, but this also has its limitations.

Comment: Edit your question. Don't post code and error messages in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as you have no real interest in getting the subtypes you get back, you can use this instead:

```
public class Ship
{
 private Set<Compartment<? extends Carriable>> allComaprtments;
}
```

Comment: Set<Compartment<?>> is sufficient. All Compartment generic types extend Carriable, by definition of the Compartment class.

Comment: Very true.  I just like to err on the side of verbosity.

Comment: And if i Would have to find out at the end how many passenger compartments and how many cargo compartments the ship has?

Comment: The best way to do that is to give your `Compartment` a method that returns the appropriate `Class<T>`, and count based on those.